# How to get/set elements in a numpy matrix by multiple indices without for-loop?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, suppose we have

```
a = zeros((5,5))
```

Then I want to set elements at positions (1,2), (3,4), (0,3) as 1,2,3 respectively at the same time, but the following would not work,

```
# I expect this to be the same as a[(1,2)] = 1, a[(3,4)] = 2, a[(0,3)] = 3
a[[(1,2),(3,4),(0,3)]] = [1,2,3]
```

It will complain "too many indices for array". I do not want to involve a for-loop for efficiency concern (the real problem is a large matrix and I need to set or get elements in that matrix with a long list of randomly generated indexes).

Comment: You want, in way or other, to index with `a[[1,3,0], [2,4,3)]]`, in other words, a list (or array) of the `i` indices, and another of the `j` indices.  This is, effectively, a transpose of your list of size 2 tuples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

rows, cols = zip(*[(1, 2), (3, 4), (0, 3)])

a = np.zeros((5,5))
a[rows, cols] = [1, 2, 3]

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[[0. 0. 0. 3. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```